# How to chain CSS selectors in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Let's say I have a `div` like this:

```
<div class="container container--modififer">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I want to target the selector like so:

```
.container.container--modifier {
   // styles
}
```

However when I do this in SASS...

```
.container {
    &--modifier {
        // styles
    }
}
```

It's compiled into CSS like:

```
.container .container--modifier {
    // styles
}
```

Which has a lower priority than the one that's chained (`.container.container--modifier`). How do I achieve this in SASS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below:

```
.container {
    &#{&}--modifier {
        //styles
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
.container.container--modifier {
   //styles
}
```

Comment: It works. I looked it up, didn't know there's a way to cache selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
    &.container--modifier {
        // styles
    }
}
```

You should use the full name of a subclass.